# Scroll view in WP 7.5

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

This is the link for the screenshot of my page (Sorry I can't upload it directly because my reputation is not enough)
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrAKV.png)

Problem in number:

1: If I scroll it up it will override my notes background so it will not look good. How I can limit the showing text to only in notes background and if I scroll it up, the text in the upper side will be vanished?

2: If I have more text in bottom side, it will cut my text. So it doesn't showing all of my text.

This is my xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="14,0,10,0">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="textScroller" Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel x:Name="Resep" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="362">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" Foreground="Black" Height="393" MaxWidth="362" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,30,1,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Height` and `Width` attributes to your ScrollViewer.